# Orbit Controls is not a constructor

Tags: three.js

I followed a tutorial of 2018 in order to add OrbitControls in an existing working project.

These are the lines of code i added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>

var controls;  // AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE

//following three lines are inside the init()
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 1;
controls.maxDistance = 1000;

//at the animate() function
controls.update();
```

However, nothing is rendered at the browser. When i take a look at the console, i see that:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     at OrbitControls.js:6
test.html:130 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor
    at init (test.html:130)
```

I found another question with a similar problem but it did not help me.
The only scripts i include are `three.js`, `OrbitControls.js`, `dat.gui.min.js`.

FULL CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 01.02 - First Scene</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.6/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = init();
    animate(); //calling function that does all the rendering 


    //GLOBAL VARS
    var scene, camera, renderer;
    var cube;
    var raycaster, mouse;
    var INTERSECTED;

    //global flag
    var isClicked = false;

    //for the camera
    var controls;

//creating and rendering the GUI
params = {
  yAxis: "0.00001"
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(params, "yAxis").onFinishChange(val => {
  cube.scale.y = parseFloat(val);
}); 

//we make sure to make it hidden
 let vis = gui.domElement.style.visibility;
 gui.domElement.style.visibility = vis == "" ? "hidden" : "";

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //SET CAMERA
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
        camera.position.z = 5;

        // create a render and set the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5"); //background color
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight); //size of renderer




        //bind rendered to the dom element
        document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);  


        //RAYCASTER
        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        mouse = new THREE.Vector2(1,1);


        // create a cube
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffff00 }); //0xF7F7F7 = gray
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.scale.y = 0.00001;
        cube.userData.originalColor = 0xffff00;

        // position the cube
        cube.position.x = 0;
        cube.position.y = 3;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        /*
        //USEFUL METHODS
        cube.rotation.x +=0.5
        cube.scale.x +=0.5
        */
        // add the cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);


        /*  RENDERING A PLANE
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        plane.rotation.set(80,0,0);
        scene.add( plane );
        //plane.position.x = 2;
        */

        //ADDING LIGHTS
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, -10);
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(spotLight);


        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);


        //camera
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.minDistance = 1;
        controls.maxDistance = 1000;

        // when the mouse moves, call the given function
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

        //when the mouse is clicked, call the given function
        document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseClick, false);
    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove(event)
    {
      // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
      // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
      event.preventDefault();

      // update the mouse variable
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;


        // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

        //TRY THIS
        // intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(cube); // to get the cube only

        //if the mouse hovers over the cube mesh, change its color to red
        //when mouse leaves the mesh, change it back to its original color
        //ONLY MAKE THESE MODIFICATION IF THE MESH IS NOT CLICKED
        //BECAUSE IF IT IS CLICKED, YOU HAVE TO PAINT THE MESH ACCORDING TO THE onDocumentMouseClick()
        if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].object === cube && isClicked === false)
        {
            cube.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        } 
        else if (isClicked === false)
        {
            cube.material.color.set( cube.userData.originalColor );
        }

    }

    function onDocumentMouseClick(event) //if we detect a click event
    {
        // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
        // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
        event.preventDefault();

        // update the mouse variable
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

        // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

        //if mouse is on top of the mesh when the click occurs, change color of mesh and render GUI
        if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].object === cube && isClicked === false)
        {
            isClicked = true;
            cube.material.color.set( 0xF7F7F7 );

/*
            var params = {
                textField: "Enter value:"
            }



                 var item =  gui.add(params, "textField").onFinishChange(function (value) {
                //Do something with the new value
                //console.log(value);
                cube.scale.y +=value;
            });

*/       

//when its clicked, change the visibily of the GUI
 vis = gui.domElement.style.visibility;
    gui.domElement.style.visibility = vis == "" ? "hidden" : "";


        } 
        //if mouse is on top of the mesh when the click occurs, but it already marked as 'clicked', now mark it as 'unclicked'
        else if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].object === cube && isClicked === true)
        {
            isClicked = false;
            cube.material.color.set( cube.userData.originalColor );
            //when its clicked, change the visibily of the GUI
            vis = gui.domElement.style.visibility;
            gui.domElement.style.visibility = vis == "" ? "hidden" : "";
   //         gui.__proto__.constructor.toggleHide()
            //dat.GUI.toggleHide();
            //gui.toggleHide()
        }


    }


    function render() 
    {
        // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
        renderer.render(scene, camera); //render the scene
    }


    function animate()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate ); //pauses when user switches tab
        controls.update();
        render();
    }




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any changes, if you use `https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js" instead?

Comment: No, its exactly the same...

Comment: No clue on why this is happening. I followed every tutorial verbatim

Comment: controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); does not work as well

Comment: Did you try removing the "type = text/javascript" when you import OrbitControls.js ?

Comment: Thanks guys! @LucienDavid that was it! If you want, make a proper answer, not a comment, so i will select it as the accepted asnwer. Prisoner849 thanks as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try removing the "type = text/javascript" when you import OrbitControls.js ?